# Java graphics problem with Intel Q965/Q963 Express chipset

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, java, dell-optiplex

The setup is this:
A Dell Optiplex 745 with an onboard Q965/Q963 Express chip and dual monitors.
Using this driver:

```
c:\windows\system32\drivers\igxpmp32.sys
(6.14.10.4642, 1.05 MB (1,095,968 Bytes), 04.07.2007 12:06)
```

Now when a Java application is running (that works fine on all other setups) it's ok on one monitor - but when you move it to the other screen, you only get a gray frame.

I have seen graphics problems like that while working via VNC. Java graphics updates seem to be elusive to some third party tools. But the graphics drivers?

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

That's a very old graphics driver.  Have you tried updating?